# Subtitle with Video-js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, video, video.js

need help my Subtitle does not work ... my subtitle file is .vtt

```
<video id="myvideo"
                               class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9"
                               controls
                               preload="auto"
                               poster="~/new/images/shahidvd.png"
                               width="640"
                               height="500"
                               data-setup='{}'>

    <source src="@Model.MovieURL" type="video/mp4" loop autoplay controls="true" />                                
    <track kind="subtitles" src="@Model.subtitleURL" srclang="ar" default />

                        </video>
```

Comment: you need to provide enough for us to diagnose it. a link to a live demo so we can (for instance) make sure the subtitles are loading and/or correctly formatted

Comment: I found the solution .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .. the Mimetype should be add to the web.config

```html
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".srt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".srt" mimeType="text/srt" />
      <remove fileExtension=".vtt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vtt" mimeType="text/vtt" />
    </staticContent>
```